# Height dependancy when adding volume from below to a fluid column

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Suppose there is a **fluid column of height H** and there is a screw already inserted from outside the column entering through the bottom of the column. The screw has a total length L   and only 0.1*L is inside the fluid column.

Let Fa be the force required to screw the screw into the column an addition 0.5*L.

Let Fb be the force required to do the same thing when **H changes to 2*H**.

**My question is**: is Fb = 2*Fa ?

If the screw end (the part that is into the column) had the shape of a sphere, would that change the relation between Fa and Fb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $F_b \approx 2 F_a$.

The force needed to advance the screw into the water is $F = PA$ where $P$ is the pressure on the end of the screw and $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the screw. When the height of the water is doubled, the pressure is also doubled.

The relation is not exact because your scenario doubles the height of the water from the bottom of the vessel, which is not exactly the same thing as doubling the height of water above the end of the screw.

Changing the shape of the screw doesn't matter; you are still doing work against pressure that is twice as great, no matter the shape of the screw.

Of course, for a real screw there is usually friction as you screw it in; I've ignored that here.

Comment: Thanks for ignoring friction. I'll wait to see if there's another take on the screw's end shape.

Comment: I'm not sure what "other take" you want. It's a simple problem and this is the answer.

Comment: Doesn't the cross-section area of the screw have an effect?  Why would there be *any* force needed to extend a needle-thin screw half its length into the water column?

Comment: If you make the screw thinner $F_a$ and $F_b$ are reduced by the same factor, so the relation between them holds.

Comment: Oh.. I read the question to say that it was the screwing in that raised the column height to 2H... My bad...

Comment: The other take I was thinking about has to do with changing the dimensions of the sphere, but that would be a different problem. Thanks for your answer.